# Keychain Sharingを有効にしたら実機インストールできなくなった

Tags: ios

Realm Mobile Platformを利用するためにCapabilitiesタブからKeychain Sharingを有効にしたのですが、以下の通り、「The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.」のエラーが出るようになってしまいました。
[image: Error]
Xcode8で、Automatically Manage Signingはonにしています。

ググり続けて数時間経ちますが、根本的な原因がわからず、質問させていただきました。

Comment: Keychain Sharingを有効にした画面のスクリーンショットと、Entitlementsファイルを載せてください。あと、Build Settingsの署名とプロビジョニングプロファイルの情報もください。`~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/`にあるプロビジョニングプロファイルをそのアプリで使うものだけ残して（他のは捨てて）やり直してみてください。もし可能ならコマンドラインでビルドしてエラーメッセージを載せてください。根本的な原因はビルド設定とプロビジョニングプロファイルの食い違いで、それは個々の環境に大きく依存するので、原因を少しずつ探っていくしかないです。

Comment: 原因がわかりました。。
Macアプリターゲットと同じentitlementsファイルをiOSでも指定していて、Mac側にしかない設定が含まれていたため、iOSのインストールが失敗していたという状況でした。
iOSターゲットではこれまでentitlementsファイルを使用していなかったため、起きていなかった問題だったようです。ご教示いただきありがとうございましたm(__)m